# Forward swipe gesture from UIView to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

The main `UIView` in my app contains a single `UIScrollView`. I've added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the main view:

```
@IBOutlet weak internal var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
  }
```

I've stubbed out the recognizer method like so... but I don't know how to pass the guesture on to the scrollview.

```
  func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.direction == .left {
      // Send left swipe to the UIScrollView
    } else if (sender.direction == .right) {
      // Send right swipe to the UIScrollView
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is:

1. a passthrough view that propagates touches through responder chain
2. simulate swipe gestures on `UIScrollView`

#### Passthrough view

You can subclass your `scrollView` and override `pointInside:event:` method

```
// you should convert this into Swift :(
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
         if (!view.hidden && view.userInteractionEnabled && 
             [view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event])
             return YES;
    }
    return NO;
 }
```

Then your custom `scrollView` will propagate the gestures on itself to other views below it and you can listen to swipe gestures in your `mainView`

#### Simulating swipe gestures on `UIScrollView`

You can do that by `setContentOffset` method of `UIScrollView`. That may feel buggy if you set content offset out of its bounds, be careful about that!

However, IMHO, the best solution would be you changing your view hierarchy and listen to swipe gesture on a view at top of your scroll view.

Comment: you can simulate swipe in your scrollView with `setContentOffset` from your `handleSwipes` function. you can't consume the same gesture on two different views automatically, this is against the idea of responder chain.

Comment: this is not what you are doing. you are listening gestures on a view which is behind another view, that's why you need to subclass your `ScrollView`

Comment: Ok, I see. The reason I'm doing this in the first place is that the user can swipe left or right on the scrollview without me having to do anything. Because the scrollview doesn't take up the entire width of the screen I wanted to detect swipes on the main view and pass them along to the scrollview. Modifying `setContentOffset` in `handleSwipes` seems like the best solution. I guess I just expected it would be easy to forward a gesture from one view to another. Thank you again.